# Subtraction of multiple date ranges in graphdb

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am trying to learn graphdb and compare its capabilities with relational databases. Consider the following problem:

I have two lists of date ranges: date-in and date-out:

Date-in date ranges:

- 1/1/2000-12/31/2025
- 1/1/2026-12/31/2030
- 2/1/2030-12/31/2033

Date-out date ranges:

- 2/1/2005-12/31/2020
- 1/1/2024-12/31/2026

**The calculation that I want to do is to subtract all the Date-out date ranges from the Date-in date ranges, meaning that I want to know all the date ranges described in the Date-in ranges that are not described in the Date-out ranges.** Note the date ranges may overlap.

The correct answer is:

- 1/1/2000-1/31/2005
- 1/1/2021-12/31/2023
- 1/1/2027-12/31/2030
- 2/1/2030-12/31/2023

**I know how to solve this problem using a relational db such as Postgres. The relational db solution would be:**

1. Use generate_series() to list all the days described in the Date-in ranges and Date-out date. There are ~33 years here, so about 12,000 days total.
2. Select all the days from the Date-in days list that are not present in the Date-out days list. This should be fast, because again, it's only ~33 years, so about 12,000 days total.
3. Use the "island" detection SQL query https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/ to find contiguous date ranges from the resulting list of days from Step 2.

**I don't have an approach to solve this problem using a graphdb gremlin traversal. I tried the same approach in graphdb as in the relational db, but there is no generate_series() in the AWS Neptune implementation of graphdb that I'm aware of. Furthermore I didn't want to add nodes to a graphdb just to run a read type query like this one.**

**Is there a graphdb solution for this problem?**

Comment: This is perhaps not the type of calculation that is easily done in Gremlin. There are some predicates such as `within`, `without` and `between` that can be used to check whether a value lies within a range but there is not an equivalent to `generate_series`. There is a `math` step but I think in general this calculation is better done in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment as an answer.

This is perhaps not the type of calculation that is easily done in Gremlin. There are some predicates such as `within`, `without` and `between` that can be used to check whether a value lies within a range but there is not an equivalent to `generate_series`. There is a `math` step that offers scientific calculator functionality, but I think in general this calculation is better done in the application.

Gremlin does allow for in-line code (lambdas/closures) to be included in a query but many Graph Database Engines do not permit that as allowing arbitrary code as part of a graph traversal can expose any number of risks. Even if that were allowed I feel that this operation is probably best done in the application rather than trying to come up with a query to do it.

In more simple cases you can test for a value being within a date range using something like:

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('date',1599830201421)
==>v[60867]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('test').has('date',between(1599830201402,1599830212143))
==>v[60867]
```